# Error restarting Apache on Windows machine via command line

Tags: windows, command-line, apache-http-server

I am having problems executing a command line to restart Apache on Windows.

The restart command I am executing is:

```
httpd.exe -k restart
```

Which I believe to be correct, but I get this back:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Admin>httpd.exe -k restart
[Mon May 19 15:37:11.319818 2014] [mpm_winnt:error] [pid 2396:tid 1956] (OS 2)Th
e system cannot find the file specified.  : AH00436: No installed service named
"Apache2.4".
```

Is there any way I can prevent this? I'm not familiar with running Apache on Windows.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Verify you installed Apache as a service.

Comment: Yes, it is installed as a service.

Comment: You have verified the service exists?  Because the error message indicates otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting exactly the same error. I did the following steps.

1. Firstly uninstall the service (as it was corrupted in my case) with command "httpd -k uninstall".(like cd  path upto bin where Apache was installed previously).
2. And then install Apache service by command "httpd -k install".
3. you will get an error like this : httpd: Syntax error on line 37 of D:/set-up/Apache2.4.6/Apache2.4.6/Apache/conf/httpd.conf: ServerRoot must be a valid directory.(Replace it with the path where Apache2.4 is extracted - "D:/set-up/Apache2.4.6/Apache2.4.6").Replace it with your appropriate path.

   4.Restart Apache with this command "httpd -k restart".

Answer (score 0):

The restart action causes Apache to reload and apply its configuration, without actually restarting the process or breaking any opened client connection, causing a so called "graceful reload".
You can check it by yourself with Windows Task Manager, the Apache PID (Process ID) won't change after a restart.

However, any action triggered by the option `-k` (they are called [signals](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/stopping.html)), needs the Apache service to exist in Windows services list.
Therefore, if you see this error message, there are only two possible causes:

### Your Apache service does not exist

Then just create it with

```
httpd.exe -h install
```

Now you should be able to send the restart signal

```
httpd.exe -k restart
```

### Your Apache service has a custom name

If the service exists, but has a custom name such as "My Awesome Apache Service", then you have to specify that name when you want to send it any signal.

So, if you have installed it with

```
httpd.exe -k install -n "My Awesome Apache Service"
```

you have to restart it with

```
httpd.exe -k restart -n "My Awesome Apache Service"
```